# Sample of using Facebook Connect with MonoTouch

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook, xamarin.ios, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using MonoTouch (latest version) and I want to be able to allow the user of my app to make a wall post based on a log entry made in this app.  All I need is a simple implementation so that the user can tap "Share on Facebook" (UIActionSheet) and then it logs them into Facebook (shows the login) and returns the token which I can then use to make the WebRequest to post to their wall.

I've seen the MonoTouch bindings on github but have no idea how to use it.  Can someone please provide a simple sample of how to just login to Facebook to retrieve a token so I can post.  I know how to do the post, it's the auth process that I'm not getting right.

Thank you.

Neal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neal,

I have added a sample that replicates about half of the Facebook sample here:

https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/facebook/sample

Comment: Just tried this sample in the latest monotouch stable build 5.2.  It doesn't build as is.  After a few fixes got it to login, but now it crashes on submitting wall post.  Is there an updated version of this sample?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use client-side javascript login more than native device login.
Sooner or later you might want an Android, Windows Phone or even Facebook version.

Having an In-App browser wrapper to deal with javascript and direct Graph API calls are easier for cross-platform implementation. Just from my personal experience.